# Printing is not available. Verify that ActiveX is enabled

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2012

I'm working on reporting service. I'm clicking on Print button of report page and getting below error.

> Message from webpage
>
> Printing is not available. Verify that ActiveX is enabled, or try using Internet Explorer for the desktop.

Can anyone please help me with proper solution. I have tried to look these links but no success.

[**Link-1**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/df190471-561b-4126-b27d-cb5e449eecab/microsoft-ssrs-2012-rsclientprint-activex-component-doesnt-installrun-within-ie-11?forum=ieitprocurrentver)

[**Link-2**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_ie/unable-to-print-an-rdl-report-in-internet-explorer/9a6114af-3e0c-412d-9436-e34b3f00cbef?auth=1)

Comment: I'm also have same problem Printing is not available. Verify that ActiveX is enabled, or try using Internet Explorer for the desktop. When I trying to print via IE11 everything ok, but in SSRS getting same message "Printing is not available. Verify that ActiveX is enabled, or try using Internet Explorer for the desktop." Cleared cache, re setup all settings, verify activeX working fine. Don know wjhat to do then.

Comment: Any update guys?

Comment: sorry man, no updates. :(

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was in 3 client-side steps :

1. Run Internet Explorer as admin.
2. In Internet Explorer, go in Compatibility View Settings and add the SSRS website.
3. Attempt to print the report. A popup asking to activate something from Microsoft SQL Services (I didn't get the exact name) should appear. Accept it (only works if running as admin). It will take a few seconds to install and then suggest a reboot, but the reboot is not required.

I could then print even without having to run as admin.
Note that I think step #3 is an add-on called "RSClientPrint 2008 Class".

I know this is a very old question, but I had the issue a few times over the years and just now found the solution. I had to try suggestions scattered across multiple sites and could not find a concise solution until I pieced this together.